# Windows Messenger Connect Invitation API Html Formatted Body

Tags: c#, windows-live-messenger

Is there any way to send HTML formatted message body using Windows Messenger Connect Invitation API?

I've many tests but I can send only plain texted messages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430657.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's plain text only. :(

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/messengerconnect/thread/b9d83e56-940c-47aa-a523-01605c1e169d